# Authentication meachanism in spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I was reading about how Authentication works in Spring and found that there are two filters taking care of the Authentication.

[AuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ui/webapp/AuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) [BasicProcessingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ui/basicauth/BasicProcessingFilter.html)

So I set breakpoints within `BasicProcessingFilter::doFilterHttp` and `AuthenticationProcessingFilter::attemptAuthentication` and `AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint::commence` and the program didn't stop at any of them.

Does it mean that my web-application currently doesn't have an authentication mechanism at all?

Maybe it has something to do with that I defined a custom resource filter as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="secureResourceFilter"
    class="my.custom.class.CustomSecureResourceFilter">
    <beans:property name="jdbcSecuredUrlRoleDao" ref="jdbcSecuredUrlRoleDao" />
</beans:bean>
```

In my Spring-security configuration I didn't define 
`AuthenticationProcessingFilter` and `BasicProcessingFilter` directly. I just specify

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect if you use Spring boot, you have to at least configure your Spring context. Either you use Java config, or XML files.

For Java config: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html
For XML files: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-security-webapp-spring-config.html

Note that you can see which are the filters used in your application by putting a break point in the delegating filter proxy and see the filter chain. Sub-filters are applied sequentially.

Comment: Where are the filters stored within DelegatingFilterProxy?

Comment: The delegate actually does the job. The delegate is retrieved from the Spring context. The proxy basically makes the link between the outside and the Spring security context. 

You have to put a breakpoint in the actual delegate.

Comment: Thatnk you. I've found it. Couldn't you explain one more thing. What filter is taking over redirecting to the login page if non-authorized user try to get a secured web-page?

Comment: For this particular case, look at LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint. This is an entry-point.

Comment: More globally if you want to track the behaviour in case of a authentication exception, put a break point where this exception is thrown. An authorization exception is basically thrown by a security voter.